# Restoring a boot drive (partition table, boot partition, and root) but restoring files from rsnapshot

Tags: partitioning, backup

I have a boot drive with the following partition scheme:

```
`sda                    8:0    0 558.9G  0 disk
|-sda1                 8:1    0   512M  0 part   /boot/efi
`-sda2                 8:2    0 102.5G  0 part
  |-fserver--vg-root 253:0    0  18.6G  0 lvm    /
  |-fserver--vg-swap 253:1    0   7.5G  0 lvm    [SWAP]
  `-fserver--vg-home 253:2    0  65.2G  0 lvm    /home
```

I have rsnapshot running on root and /home. I'd like to implement some additional backup/imaging so that I could restore the drive entirely with the following process (or something like it):

1. Boot into liveCD
2. Restore partition table, including lvm config, and boot partition
3. Copy files from rsnapshot back to root and /home

The idea here is to have easily accessible incremental file backups through rsnapshot, but also be able to restore the whole drive without saving the entire contents of the drive twice.

How can I do this easily?

Clonezilla doesn't seem to have an option to image the partition scheme without saving the contents as well. I think I can use sgdisk to back up the partition table, then possibly clonezilla to image the boot partition, then vgcfgbackup to save the lvm metadata (though I guess that will come over when I copy the files on root?). An all-in-one solution would be much preferred, though.

Comment: Restoring a partition table from backup without restoring the partitions  is a dangerous thing, it will work when the partition table has never been changed (resizing, moving partitions) since you created the backup of the partition table. I think the same point is valid for backups of the lvm configuration, if the configuration has been changed since the last backup you are likely running in trouble by restoring. That means whenever you make changes to the partition table or the lvm configuration you will have to create a backup of it.

Comment: Seems you use UEFI. If your drive uses GPT (not MBR or msdos partitioning scheme) you always have a valid backup of your current partition table at the end of the disk and you should be able to restore the partition table from this backup with `gdisk` in the case the primary partition table at the start of the disk is corrupted.